# Removing from an Array without holes

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `Array` of `Car`s that contains `Car` objects and I've been stuck for a while now on the method that gets a car number and needs to delete all objects that has that car number and then return that array without any holes. it's my homework so I can't use any `arrayList` or `Array.` methods.

I've tried to do the following but for some reason when I try to run it, it doesn't complie and gives me a `IndexOutOfBounds` error and refer me to my `toString` method(it prints all of the cells in the array).

`noOfCars`, saves the amount of cars there actually is right now as we built the array with a container constructor for holding more places for future cars just in case.

```
public void removeCarNumbers(int CarNum) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.noOfCars; i++) {
        if(this.cars[i].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
            this.cars[i] = this.cars[noOfCars- 1 - count];
            count++;
        }
    }
    CarsLines [] newArr = new CarLines[this.noOfCars- count];

    for(int i = 0; i< this.noOfCars - count; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = this.cars[i];
    }
    this.cars= newArr;
}
```

*edit: after playing with it more I still get an error that refers me to my toString() method. is there a problem with it as well?
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.noOfCars; i++)
            output += "" + this.cars[i].toString() + "\n";
        return output;
    }

Comment: Just to be clear, if you are getting an "IndexOutOfBounds" error, it is compiling.

Comment: Why don't you use a `List`??

Comment: @user3604476 I made an edit in response to your addition about the `toString` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think those two loops are doing what you think they are.  In the first loop you should eliminate `Car`s which have the same number, perhaps setting them to `null`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
    if (this.cars[i] != null && this.cars[i].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
        this.cars[i] == null;
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
```

This will now eliminate duplicates, and keep a count of unique `Car`s.  In the second loop, fill in just the non-`null` values:

```
CarsLines [] newArr= new CarLines[count];
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< this.cars,length; i++)
{
    if (this.cars[i] != null) { // Only pass in the non-null values
        newArr[index] = this.cars[i]; 
        index++;
    }
}
this.cars= newArr;
```

Before you had this creating pretty much an identical copy of your list because you were filling it in on a one-to-one basis i.e. the same index.

Another possible way of doing this would be an in place conversion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
    if (this.cars[i] != null && this.cars[i].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < this.cars.length; j++) { // This loop will shift the 
            this.cars[j-1] = this.cars[j];             // whole list down one when
        }                                              // a duplicate is found,
                                                       // overwriting it.
        i--;              // sets the index back to recheck the shifted list.
        this.noOfCars--;  // You removed one duplicate by overwriting it
    }
}
```

In response to **@Boris The Spiders** Comment, you could reduce the complexity of this algorithm by eliminating the inner `for` loop.  I would recommend doing this by tracking the last valid position and using that for updating.

```
int writeIndex = 0;
for (int readIndex = 0; readIndex < this.cars.length; readIndex++) {
    if (this.cars[readIndex] != null && this.cars[readIndex].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
        // pass on this because nextIndex should track only the valid cars.
    } else {
        this.cars[writeIndex++] = this.cars[readIndex];
    }
    if (writeIndex < readIndex) {
        this.cars[i] = null;
    }
}
```

The idea is that you keep one index for reading (`i`) and one index for writing `writeIndex`.  If your `readIndex` gets ahead of your `writeIndex` (this means you found a duplicate) you should clear it after it is read, and you will transer if to the previous `writeIndex`.

**EDIT**    In response to the addition to your question, you should be extra careful on how `noOfCars` is calculated as this is probably the source of your `Exception`, instead try a more reliable indexing method by using the intrinsic `length` property from your array:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
        if (this.cars[i] != null) {
            output += "" + this.cars[i].toString() + "\n";
        } else {
            // condition that the i-th car is null
            output += "null\n"; // one possible approach
            // you could also do nothing and your toString would output just the non-null cars
         }
    }
    return output;
}
```

for reliability, at the cost of efficiency, you could implement a `count()` method to double check your tracking.  Maybe as a temporary check until your sure it is working correctly.

```
public int getNumCars() {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
        if (this.cars[i] != null) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You're better off looping twice, this algorithm is `O(n^2)` whereas it should be `O(n)`. Loop once to set `null` then loop a second time to shift; when you find the first `null` shift `1`, if you find a second `null` start shifting `2` etc. You can, of course, do that with a single loop - but that gets very convoluted.

Comment: @BoristheSpider My apologies, I was doing the mental math wrong and your suggestion is valid, I made an attempt at a similar method in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
// count
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < this.cars.length ; ++i) {
    if(this.cars[i].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
        ++count;
    }
}
// create new array
CarsLines[] newArr = new CarLines[this.cars.length - count];
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < this.cars.length ; ++i) {
    if(this.cars[i].getCarNum() != CarNum) {
        newArr[index++] = this.cars[i];
    }
}
// assign
this.cars = newArr;
```

Comment: Yes. This is pretty much what he was doing.

Comment: You get my vote, as this answer is certainly correct. Just a note to the OP that the intent of the exercise is probably to rearrange the elements in place.

Comment: Maybe. But it cannot be entirely in place because of the length of the array. After re-arranging, the end of the original array would be empty.

Comment: This is how an `ArrayList` works - obviously there's some snazzy logic to grow/shrink the array.

Comment: @Vakh there was no mention of whether having parts of the array empty would be invalid, in fact the OP indicates that it is not only expected but set up that way in the first place: `as we built the array with a container constructor for holding more places for future cars just in case.`

Comment: @Vakh not to diminish your answer, just the comment you made on whether this could be accomplished using an in place conversion.

Comment: No problem at all. Whatever helps to answer the question properly :)

Comment: I'm still getting IndexOutOfBounds error and it still refers me to my toString() method. maybe the issue is there?
    public String toString()
    {
     String output = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < this._noOfCars; i++)
      output += "" + this.cars[i].toString() + "\n";
     return output;
    }

Comment: I don't know what ``noOfCars`` is. Use ``this.cars.length`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For every car that you remove try swapping the last element in the array into the "hole". Keepa counter for the max element that is valid and decrement it everytime you swap out an element into the hold. You are basically rearragning the array elemtns in place

```
int max=this.noOfCars.length; 
int i=0;
do{
        if(this.cars[i]==null)
            break; 
        if(this.cars[i].getCarNum() == CarNum) {
            this.cars[i] = this.cars[max-1];
            this.cars[max-1] = null;
        }
         else{
            i++;
         } 
   }while(1==1);
```

PS: you might have to add a few checks for boundary conditions(like empty array)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to do this with a single loop, no nested loops.

The idea is that you keep track of how maybe elements you have removed (also how many `null` elements you have found) and then, if the current element is not to be removed, just shift it back by that number.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Integer[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 2, null, null, null};
    int shift = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (data[i] == null || data[i] == 2) {
            shift++;
            data[i] = null;
        } else if (shift > 0) {
            data[i - shift] = data[i];
            data[i] = null;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

So you can see the `2`s have been removed and the rest have been shifted up.